# JAVA try catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I would like to Rewrite the getContents method below to incorporate exception handling. In particular, when an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is generated, the method should return the value -1.0

```
public class Four
{
 private double [] numbers = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};

 public double getContents(int index)
 {
 return numbers[index];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Four
{
    private double [] numbers = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};

    public double getContents(int index)
    {
       try
       {
          return numbers[index];
       }
       catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
       {
          return -1.0;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
    return numbers[index] ;
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it this way

```
public double getContents(int index)
 {
  try {
   return numbers[index];
  } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
   return -1.0;
  }
 }
```

otherwise you could just check if the index is larger than the size of your array.